# Symfony2 how to fix deploy kernel error

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

Hi i deployed my app to my server and i got some karnel error.
J have no idea what can couse it, maybe assets or something?

here is the error:

```
ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.debug".
in /home/public_html/ProjecName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php line 106
at ParameterBag->get('kernel.debug') in /home/public_html/ProjecName/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1954
at Container->getParameter('kernel.debug') in /home/public_html/ProjecName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/FrameworkBundle.php line 85
at FrameworkBundle->build(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/public_html/ProjecName/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2557
at Kernel->prepareContainer(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/public_html/ProjecName/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2537
at Kernel->buildContainer() in /home/public_html/ProjecName/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2490
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /home/public_html/ProjecName/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2270
at Kernel->boot() in /home/public_html/ProjecName/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2301
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /home/public_html/ProjecName/web/app.php line 16
```

Maybe someone had something similar and know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you clear cache? Try `rm -Rf app/cache/*`.